# User.find({}) not returning in console properly in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-router

I am pretty new to mongodb and backend development in general, and I am having difficulty trying to query my mongodb. I am simply trying to create a route that returns all the users in "users" database that have a bullets property greater than 0. I will post my users model below.

Right now in my getUsers controller, I am simply trying to console.log the result, to no success.  Eventually what I am trying to achieve is this getUsers route will be triggered in my indexRouter.js by my /dashboard route. Then I will need to pass the result to the client. Again, I am pretty new to express and back end dev so any help would be great!

I am including the github repo for any server and/or config related issues, outside of the files I posted here on stack.  The .js files I have examples of on stack are more current than my github repo files, but all other files should be the same.

### [Full Github Repo](https://github.com/JordanVera/survivor_league_app)

### userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  bullets: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

### userController.js (i didnt include all the controllers just the one I am trying to work on right now)

```
const User = require('./userModel');
const passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


exports.getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
console.log(User.find({ bullets: { $gt: 0 } }))
}
```

### userRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('./userController');

router.route('/login')
  .get(controller.getLogin)
  .post(controller.postLogin)

router.route('/register')
  .get(controller.getRegister)
  .post(controller.postRegister)

router.route('/logout')
  .get(controller.getLogout)

router.route('/buyBullet')
  .get(controller.buyBullet);

router.route('getUsers')
  .get(controller.getUsers);




module.exports = router;
```

### indexRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../../config/auth');


router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('dashboard', {
    name: req.user.name
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `Model.find()` is an asynchronous function so when you `console.log` the function call it will log the promise returned by the call. If you want to use it as middleware I suggest making the `controller.getUsers` function asynchronous and awaiting the `Model.find()` call

userController.js:

```js
exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(await User.find({ bullets: { $gt: 0 } }))
}
```

Comment: that code snippet isnt working for me but I was thinking it had to be an async issue causing the problem.

Comment: @Jordan I have a theory that it might have to do with your ensureAuthenticated middleware. Can you edit the post and add in the code for that

Comment: Nevermind, I looked through the repo and that isn't the issue

Comment: Right now I am just trying to test the route, so that when I hit the route in my browser it simply console.logs all the  users with greater than 0 bullet count.  It isnt being triggered by my dashboards route yet but that is the end goal.

Comment: WOOOOWWWWW. Look at my usersRoutes.js file.  There is no / in front of my URI. LOL.

Comment: @AbirTaheer man I owe you a bottle of beer!